# NSDateFormatter applies no formatting at all to NSDate

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

My datepicker is sending a date to a label. However, I am trying to format my date in the label to MM/dd/yyyy. Somehow, this is not working, although I am using the following code:

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height+44, 768, 216)];
datePicker.tag = 10;
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[datePicker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:datePicker];
```

And then I am unsuccessfully trying to change the label to the date selected:

```
- (void)changeDate:(UIDatePicker *)sender {


    NSLog(@"New Date: %@", sender.date);


    NSDate *date_JF = sender.date;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatJF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatJF setLocale:([[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"])];
    [dateFormatJF setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatJF setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

    FeeDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", date_JF];

}
```

Can anyone help me format my label to MM/dd/yyyy?

Comment: How do you expect the formatter to format your date if you don't give it the date?

Comment: I thought that NSDate *date_JF = sender.date; is taking care of this... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't even created the formatter at that point; how could it have an effect? gabriellanata's answer tells you what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to use `NSDateFormatter` is by getting the formatted date with the `stringFromDate:` method. Therefore you need to change the last line of your code to:

```
FeeDate.text = [dateFormatJF stringFromDate:date_JF];
```